# first backword letter is always undefined

Tags: javascript

```
function spinWords(string){
  var backwords = [];

  regex = /\b[a-zA-Z]{5,}\b/g
  var fiveletter = string.match(regex);
  for (let i = 0; i<fiveletter.length; i++)
    for (let t=fiveletter[i].length; t--;)
      backwords[i] += fiveletter[i][t]; 

  return backwords;
  //TODO Have fun :)
}
```

when i printout fiveletter[i][t] i dont have undefined however when i added to my backwords[i] array, the first char is always undefined. Can anyone explain why that is?

Thanks

Comment: You always use `+=` to append characters, so the first time the array element will be `undefined`.

Comment: @Pointy thanks, i thought that was the problem too, but i cant use =+, is there another way of doing it?

Comment: Just initialize it before appending. So `backwords[i] = "";` before the second loop.

Comment: @DanielBlack haha, thats just what i did a min ago too. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
function spinWords(string){
  var backwords = [];

  regex = /\b[a-zA-Z]{5,}\b/g
  var fiveletter = string.match(regex);
  for (let i = 0; i<fiveletter.length; i++)
  {
    backwords[i] =""
    for (let t=fiveletter[i].length; t--;)
      backwords[i] += fiveletter[i].charAt(t); 
  }
    
  return backwords;
  //TODO Have fun :)
}
```

i added backwords[i] ="" in the first for loop

Answer (score 0):

Simpler code...

```js
function spinWords(string) {
  const fiveletter = !string ? [] : string.match(/\b[a-zA-Z]{5,}\b/g); let backwords = []; 
  fiveletter !== null ? fiveletter.forEach((w) => backwords.push(w.split('').reverse().join(''))) : backwords = [] ;
  return backwords;
}

console.log(spinWords('Spin words that contains five letters or more'));
```